# Не выводится список всех программ в label

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытаюсь с помощью wmic вывести в форме список программ, но ничего не происходит. Вот код:

```
Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "cmd",
    Arguments = "wmic product get name",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
});
label1.Text = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `Arguments = "/C wmic...` или сразу wmic запускайте без cmd, ни к чему он тут `FileName = "wmic", Arguments = "product...`. А вообще WMI запросы можно слать прямо из C#, поизучайте `System.Management`

Comment: Или даже так https://stackoverflow.com/a/648428/12888024

Comment: Документация WMI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/enumerating-wmi

Comment: Спасибо, получилось обоими способами)